# Passing data to ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive( that takes a list and turns it into a grid. Each "cell" of the grid has a clone of the transcluded content. Currently I'm trying to pass each cell some data biased on the current item of the list

My directives template is:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in grid">
    <div ng-repeat="item in row">
      <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current attempt is here: https://jsfiddle.net/46ybLt0g/3/

How do I fix this?

Comment: I believe your issue is that you're trying to transclude content, but your ng-transclude directive is within another directive, ng-repeat (actually there are two repeats).  In fact, looking at your code, you're trying to display item.name, and item is from your inner ng-repeat.  There may be additional issues with reaching your ng-transclude directive within those two ng-repeats, but the context in which you placed item.name is definitely incorrect, it should be within your directive's code as an ng-bind or simiar in place of that ng-transclude. https://jsfiddle.net/k3en7w23/

Comment: Sorry maybe my intention was not correctly explained. I'm attempting to use the ng-transclude, so the grid may be used elsewhere, with the intention of changing what is displayed in the cell.

Comment: I think you've really already got a design that will work in that respect. The only thing you need to do is to make sure the items being repeated have a name property and you can reuse this anywhere you'd like. I want to say that there are other ways to design it to get it closer to what I _think_ you may be trying to do, but there's almost no reason, because this does actually work. But I think the best thing I can do is to point out that those ng-repeats create their own scopes, and GridCtrl has no direct access to them. So you may want to look at that further while trying to refactor.

Comment: Ok I've made a fiddle to attempt to show what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/jackbuzza/zy5s0unq/3/ by reuse

Answer (score 2):

You need to look further into how scope works in Angular.  Take a look here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Notice in the second sentence it specifies that directives with isolate scopes and/or transclusion don't prototypically inherit.  This doesn't really affect your code directly as its set up, but it should help clue you in to why this isn't working, as, in your setup, your directive has a completely different scope from your controller.

You have a ng-repeat in your directive that's nested below another ng-repeat, with a repeated object called `item`.  From your parent controller you're trying to reference `item.name`, which doesn't exist in that context.  It actually only exists on the scope of the inner ng-repeat directive.

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsz7o1k9/

Open your browser's console and take a moment to look at what's printed.  You won't see an `item` property in any of the scopes there.  Most importantly, look at the scope from your directive.  There's a $parent property.  This is your controller `GridCtrl`'s scope.  You can verify this by looking at the $id of each of the scopes to see which is which.

Your ng-repeat has a scope that looks very similar, but its parent is, either the other ng-repeat's scope, or your directive `gridList`'s scope.  Because they're nested like this, you can't actually expect to be able to access the `item` property of ng-repeat's scope from your controller's scope.

There is a path to these child scopes through the $$ChildScope property on your controller's scope, but the double dollar ($$) is angular's convention to signify a private property.  What this, in effect, means to us is that we cannot rely on it being there in later versions of angular, so it shouldn't be used.

So, there's always a path up from child scopes to the parent, but not down.  And getting from the child scope to the parent can get ugly quickly (e.g. `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.obj.prop`), just not a good way to write code in my opinion.

Child scopes that aren't from a directive using an isolate scope and/or transclusion inherit from their parent scope, so you could in theory set a property on your controller's scope and directly access it in a directive with `scope: true` set.  Be sure you read through the article I mentioned at the top, however, as this has some gotchas.

But, what does this mean for your directive and how should you go about refactoring to do what you want?  This is where you're going to have to be a little imaginative and experiment.  And there may not be a 'one size fits all' solution to this.  You may have to make some decisions about how many configurations your application is going to need and account for each individually within your directive.

I realize this may not have been the answer you were hoping for, but hopefully that at least gets your head where it needs to be to know how to tackle the problem!

Comment: couldnt i just create my own transclude directive and pass the scope that way e.g. ` .directive('myTransclude', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope,function(clone, scope){
        el.append(clone);
      })
      
    }
  };
});`